# Private methods using .NET reflection. Why?

Tags: .net, reflection, methods, private

I used reflection many times before on public methods, but I never realized that private methods can be invoked too. See *[Reflection with private members](http://www.codingday.com/reflection-with-private-members/)*.

Why is that allowed in the first place? Isn't that going to break the rule of "private" being "private"?

Comment: That link is broken. Has it moved somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`private` in C# is truly only part of the language specification; in the C# language, as well as in the Visual Basic language or any other sensible .NET language (including [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), what all the .NET languages compile to) one is prevented from accessing a `private` (or `protected`, if you're not within a derived class) member **in the language**. However, just because the language doesn't support publicly accessing `private` or `protected` members doesn't mean **the underlying framework** can't provide access to those members.

This is one of those cases where one typically **shouldn't** be using workarounds like reflection to access or modify `private` or `protected` members, but the framework allows one to anyway. Generally, you should have a **very** good reason to access `private` or `protected` members; one such reason, for example, is implementing a serializer that needs to look at the object's internal state to properly serialize the object. If you're not doing something like that, you should truly look at reimplementing the class you're poking around inside, so that you don't need to use reflection in your program.

Answer (score 4):

This is only allowed when the code is running under full trust (or with the relevant permission). Otherwise, a `MethodAccessException` will be thrown.

The framework is perfectly able to restrict access appropriately - it just doesn't do so when you're running under full trust or when you have specific permissions. See ["Security Considerations for Reflection"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc.aspx) for more details of when you're able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is advanced power you get from the framework. It is very uncommon to use it in production code for invoking methods, it breaks the advantages of members hiding.

There are some places where it can be useful:

- **Legacy code testing** - For example, assume you are working with legacy code and you want to cover it with unit tests. If you're not allowed to change the code and you want to test small part of the functionality invoking private methods is useful.
- **Hacks in production code** - I encountered once a bug in 3rd party control where in some scenario a private cleanup was not done. Using private invoke I could work around it.

There is nothing wrong with the framework providing this functionality, but using it where it's not a must is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it does break the rule.  I'd almost never pass code during a review if someone did this.

Using reflection to call a method is slllloooow, not type-safe, and breaks easily if the underlying class has the private methods reworked.

So in short, I agree, it's a bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is a powerful functionality in .NET but has also its cons.

**Pros:**

1. Reflection permits accessing all members (including the private and protected), provided that you have at least the **ReflectionPermission** security.  (This permission can be gained when your application accesses the reflected assembly from the same drive, not from the Internet.)
2. In some rare cases, reflection is the only way to perform a task.

**Cons:**

1. Reflection breaks security (as does decompiling an assembly).  To gain complete security over your application's code and data, you must use cryptography, not just rely on the Private or Protected keywords because, if alone, can be easily broken through reflection or decompilation.
2. Reflection is much slower and consumes more resources than static referencing (the normal way you call methods).  For this reason, you should avoid reflection unless this is the only way to solve your problem.

**Examples** of when reflection is the only way to solve the problem follow:

1. Suppose your application dynamically compiles code (such as when you're plotting functions that the user provide at run-time).  In such cases, the only way to load the assemblies and types is through reflection.
2. You want to clone an object.  You'd need to use reflection to access its private fields.

I hope this helps.
I should thank here Mr. Francesco Balena for his beautiful book, Programming Microsoft Visual Basic 2005: The Language.